# Ring map inducing map on spectra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider the ring map $f:\mathbb{C}[y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]$ given by $y\mapsto x^2$. This induces a maps on the spectra: $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[y]$ sending the ideal $(x-a)$ (where $a\in\mathbb{C}$) to $f^{-1}((x-a))$. However, what is $f^{-1}((x-a))$ concretely? I feel like it should be something like $(y-a)$ where $y=\sqrt{x}$ although this doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f^{-1}((x-a))$ is a prime ideal which contains $(y-a^2)$.

Comment: Does this follow from $f(y-a^2)=x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)\in(x-a)$?

Comment: yes it follows from that.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(x)\in(x-a)$ and $p(x)$ only has even-degree terms (which is what it would take to lie in the image of $f$), then $p(a)=p(-a)=0$ so $p(x)=(x^2-a^2)g(x^2)$ for some polynomial $g$ (and this works even for $a=0$), and conversely.  Hence $f^{-1}((x-a))=(y-a^2)$.